# Inserting and retrieving data in MySQL using PHP through Ajax

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, forms

I have a very simple form, containing a textbox and a submit button. When the user enters something into the form, then clicks submit, I would like to use PHP and Ajax (with jQuery) to insert the result of the form into a MySQL database. this result should be displayed on the same page in the form of a table which is updated after every insert.

Can anyone please help?

The code I have used that isn’t working:

`ajax.html`:

```
<html>
<body>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!-- 
//Browser Support Code
function ajaxFunction(){
 var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

 try{
   // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
   ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
 }catch (e){
   // Internet Explorer Browsers
   try{
      ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
   }catch (e) {
      try{
         ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }catch (e){
         // Something went wrong
         alert("Your browser broke!");
         return false;
      }
   }
 }
 // Create a function that will receive data 
 // sent from the server and will update
 // div section in the same page.
 ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
   if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
      var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('ajaxDiv');
      ajaxDisplay.value = ajaxRequest.responseText;
   }
 }
 // Now get the value from user and pass it to
 // server script.
 var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
var age = document.getElementById('age').value;
 var wpm = document.getElementById('wpm').value;
 var sex = document.getElementById('sex').value;
 var queryString = "&name=" +name+ "&age=" + age ;
 queryString +=  "&wpm=" + wpm + "&sex=" + sex;
 ajaxRequest.open("GET", "ajax-example.php" + 
                              queryString, true);
 ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
//-->
</script>
<form name='myForm'>
Name: <input type='text' id='name' /><br/>
Max Age: <input type='text' id='age' /> <br />
Max WPM: <input type='text' id='wpm' />
<br />
Sex: <select id='sex'>
<option value="m">m</option>
<option value="f">f</option>
</select>
<input type='button' onclick='ajaxFunction()' 
                              value='Query MySQL'/>
</form>
<div id='ajaxDiv'>Your result will display here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

`ajax-example.php`:

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "demo";
$dbpass = "demo";
$dbname = "test_db";
    //Connect to MySQL Server
mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    //Select Database
mysql_select_db($test_db) or die(mysql_error());
    // Retrieve data from Query String
$age = $_GET['age'];
$sex = $_GET['sex'];
$wpm = $_GET['wpm'];
    // Escape User Input to help prevent SQL Injection
$age = mysql_real_escape_string($age);
$sex = mysql_real_escape_string($sex);
$wpm = mysql_real_escape_string($wpm);
    //build query
$query = "INSERT INTO form2 (name,age,sex,wpm) VALUES ('$name','$age','$sex','$wpm')";;


mysql_select_db('test_db');

$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}

    //Build Result String
$display_string = "<table>";
$display_string .= "<tr>";
$display_string .= "<th>Name</th>";
$display_string .= "<th>Age</th>";
$display_string .= "<th>Sex</th>";
$display_string .= "<th>WPM</th>";
$display_string .= "</tr>";

// Insert a new row in the table for each person returned
$result1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM form2 WHERE name='$name'"); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{
    $display_string .= "<tr>";
    $display_string .= "<td>$row[name]</td>";
    $display_string .= "<td>$row[age]</td>";
    $display_string .= "<td>$row[sex]</td>";
    $display_string .= "<td>$row[wpm]</td>";
    $display_string .= "</tr>";

}

$display_string .= "</table>";
echo $display_string;
?>
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: i have used php to accept and retrieve data from db. the data is displayed on the next page. i wanted data to be displayed on the same page

Answer (score 1):

```
$("button_id").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url:"where you should post the data",
        type: "POST",  
        data: the string you should post,  
        success: function (result) {
            //display your result in some DOM element
        }
    });
});
```

When you receive the data in the php script make query to the database and get your result

hope this would help

Answer (score 0):

There are many tutorials available on internet for ajax with PHP and Jquery. You can go through any of these and get the desired result.

See an example here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ajax/ajax_database.htm

Comment: it retrieves the results from db. what changes are to be made if i want to insert into db and then retrieve?

Comment: Replace the 'select' query with 'Insert' query. See this example
http://woork.blogspot.com/2007/10/insert-record-into-database-using-ajax.html

Comment: its not working. database isnt getting updated after submitting the from. infact nothing happens on pressing submit

Comment: `code` 
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
   if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
      var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('ajaxDiv');
      ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
   }


We dont have a value attribute for a div. You need to use innerHTML attribute.

Comment: And your query string is wrong.
`code`
    var queryString = "?name=" +name+ "&age=" + age ;
    queryString +=  "&wpm=" + wpm + "&sex=" + sex;
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "ajax-example.php" + 
                              queryString, true);

you need to replace the first '&' with a '?'.